# Not using network-manager and modem-manager

Tags: init.d

What is the best way to prevent network-manager (and modem-manager for that matter) from starting?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove network-manager` is not an alternative?

Comment: Do you plan to use ifupdown then? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to test starting a ppp session over a G3 broadband modem that eventually will run on an embedded system (which won't have network-manager, but isn't available yet).
My test machine DOES have network-manager enabled and it will spawn modemmanager which grabs the modem right away, and hence my ppp chat scripts can't access it. Even if I stop network-manager and kill modemmanager, the modem (/dev/ttyUSB2) somehow doesn't get released.
I just found out that simply moving network-manager.conf out of /etc/init will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Just found out that removing `/etc/init/network-manager.conf` does the trick.